# TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function. (In firebase.auth();'firebase.auth' is undefined) socorro

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, react-native, expo

Eu já tentei todo os tutoriais possíveis na internet e nada resolveu, estou com o *firebase": "^9.6.7", web App* em um projeto typescript utilizando expo.

Criei a conexão e na hora de gravar ele fica me apresentando esse erro:

```
TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function. (In firebase.auth();'firebase.auth' is undefined)
```

Esse maldito auth não funciona mais e não sei como arrumar. Já desistalei a pasta node_modules instalei o npm tudo de novo, já usei todos os tipos de import e nada, quem puder ajudar eu agradeço o codigo está abaixo.:

Meu arquivo de conexão **Firebase.tsx**

```
import * as firebase  from 'firebase/app';
require('firebase/firestore')
require ('firebase/auth');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*******",
    authDomain: "**********",
    projectId: "**********",
    storageBucket: "*********",
    messagingSenderId: "******",
    appId: "*******"
  };
  


  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  const db = app.firestore
  const auth = app.auth

  export { auth };
  export default db;
```

Meu arquivo de gravação: **user.tsx**:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import db from '../config/Firebase';


export const updateEmail = (input) => {
    return {type:'UPDATE_EMAIL', payload: input}
}
export const updateSenha = (input) => {
    return {type:'UPDATE_SENHA', payload: input}
}

export const updateUsername = (input) => {
    return {type:'UPDATE_USERNAME', payload: input}
}


export const cadastro = () =>{
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        try{
            const { username, email, senha, } = getState().user
            //aqui que ocorre o erro no auth, ele não reconhece esse auth()
            const response = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndsenha(email,senha)
          
            if(response.user.uid){
                const user = {
                    uid: response.user.uid,
                    username:username,
                    email: email,
                    posts: [],
                    bio: '',
                    likes:0,
                    photo: ''
                }
                await db.collection('users').doc(response.user.uid).set(user)
                dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', payload: user})
                alert('Cadastrado com sucesso!')
            }
        }catch(e){
            alert(e)
        }
    }
}
```

E sim já tentei os

```
imports com @, sem @, com 
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
```

já tentei os auth assim: auth() e firestore() e nada, sempre acaba nesse erro. já olhei a documentação e nada funciona, até no stack já vi duvidas assim, nenhuma das soluções funcionou, preciso de ajuda urgente, não aguento mais quebrar a cabeça com isso.

Comment: Talvez funcione se você mencionar as informações da sua conta de serviço em `firebaseConfig`. É um json que você baixa lá no Google Cloud Platform, aí põe o diretório dele dentro do `firebaseConfig` num campo chamado `service_account.json`. Se não encontrar o json para baixar, me dá um toque.

Comment: Poxa obrigado, eu consegui resolver, pois descobri que a função aut() foi desativada nessa nova versão do firebase vou colocar o código caso alguém precise.  De qualquer forma muito Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente consegui resolver caso alguém precise eu vou deixar o código abaixo. Eu descobri que nessa nova versão do firebase 9.6 o aut() foi desativado, então vc tem que chamar assim:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
```

e chama no seu código da seguinte forma:

```
const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, senha)
```

Espero que ajude alguém. Vlw